# How to get a specific value from column & insert it in field, when using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, database, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am working in selenium web driver & stuck in a scenario. I have to get login code from column & save it in a variable
The text in column "message _generated" is

"Dear Adnan, Your passcode is 7856, Please use this password & don't share this with anyone"

I want to pick the code "7856", & save it in a variable. Need help. I am using Java Web Driver.
Please note that DB connections & all other stuff are working fine.

Comment: so try coding something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code assign the passcode from your message to messageCode variable. It's only example how to retrieve this code from text. I hope you know how to get text from that "message_generated" column because without any details noone helps you

```
String message = "Dear Adnan, Your passcode is 7856, Please use this password & don't share this with anyone";
String template = "Your passcode is ";
String messageCode = message.substring(message.indexOf(template) + template.length(), message.indexOf(',', message.indexOf(template) + template.length()));
System.out.println(messageCode);
```

Comment: Got the logic... Thanks for the response Rafal